# How to create a counter into chunk function closure without reset value?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, closures

I use a chunk method closure of Laravel 5.

But when function closure get a new chunk, reset var.

```
...
$var = 0;
DB::connection('mysql_old')->table($table)->orderBy('uid')->whereNotNull('uid')->chunk(100, function($suppliers)
        use ($table, $checks, $faker,$missing,$var)
{
    // Some code
       ++$var;
}
```

if use a `$var` passed into `use ($var)` on every new chunk, `$var` reset to 0.

How it's best way for crate and user a counter into closure?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to pass it by reference `function() use(&$var) {}`

If you don't pass by reference all you're passing is the value so any modifications are scoped to the function just like a normal parameter.

Comment: A lot of thanks. I don't know well, use var pass by reference. Now, I know.

Comment: That is correct! Pass by value would copy over and give you a different instance of that variable. Pass by reference would actually give you the memory address of that variable, therefore you would be changing the variable from outside.

Comment: Thanks! 1st time in my life actually using & understanding this `&` thing 